# Merging curves created one curve object with two connected splines in it - how to fix?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, workflow

I have two bezier curves. I can't join them no matter what I try. Pressing <kbd>F</kbd> when two nearest vertices of bezier are selected does nothing. The curves are in same direction and non-cyclic. However I did manage to join them somehow. My current issue is that I have 1 curve object which is two splines. One of the splines has no segments so the curve is now ignored by all other objects.

How do I make the curve into one spline that has segments? Below is a blend file of the issue:
https://www44.zippyshare.com/v/YMcWVaJz/file.html

Here is an image that kinda shows the issue:
[image]

Comment: If the question is about the addon, and not general workflow then [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) and/or images would be especially helpful to help users understand your problem.

Comment: Blender does not allow a curve with branching points.  It allows multiple segments.  You can join two curves by connecting end points. Maybe if you write about your final goal in your question then readers can make better suggestions.  Can you use multiple curve objects to achieve your goal?  Can you state what failed?

Comment: It is not a branch. Just two splines inside one curve object with apparently one of the splines not having segments. Just open the blend file. Try to set another object to it sing the curve modifier for example. There is something weird going on.